# How to use async.waterfall with external asynchronous functions (RedisSMQ)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, server, iteration, waterfall

I have a rsmq server, that should check whether given URLs contain an image. I need to make the program run synchronously, as there's an `init()` function and a `while(true)` loop to serve all requests.

**First**, the loop is called before the `init()` function.

**Second**, I want the loop to wait for each iteration to finish before it continues looping, so it won't cause a heap overflow.

Trying to use async.waterfall. My code:
[Pastebin.com link](http://pastebin.com/LDQRmx4Y)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad practice to use `while (true)` because it's blocking and will emit huge amount of requests instead of one as you ezpected. Use `async.during`:

```
async.whaterfall([
    (done) => {
        // do some async stuff
        done(null, false);
    },
    (isLoaded, callback) => { // isLoaded is false
        async.during(
            () => ! isLoaded, // Test async function result
            (done) => { // Run check
                checkIsLoaded((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        done(err);
                    } else {
                        isLoaded = true;
                    }
                })
            },
            callback
        )
    }
], (err, result) => {
    // result got...
);
```

Comment: Honestly I didn't quite get it, can you please elaborate? Maybe use my given example